# Vbscript rename a remote folder

Tags: vbscript, rename

I'm working on a script that renames a folder on a remote pc. But it it's not working.
Iff I execute the script nothing happens. I use a modified version of the Hey Scripting Guy blog. If I use normal pathnames (c:\data) instead of remotepath names (\\"& strcomputer &"C$\data) it works. But if i use remote pathnames nothing happens.
Do you guys know whats wrong?

```
strComputer = "hostname"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFolders = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_Directory Where Name = '\\\\"& strComputer &"C$\\Data'")

For Each objFolder in colFolders
strNewName = objFolder.Name & ".old"
objFolder.Rename strNewName
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish your task using the FileSystemObject...

```
strComputer = "hostname"

strFolderName = "\\"& strComputer &"\C$\Data"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FolderExists(strFolderName) Then
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)
    strNewName = objFolder.Name & ".old"
    objFolder.Name = strNewName
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

When you connect with WMI you don't use a UNC path with Win32_Directory (since it's local to that WMI repository).

So use `("Select * From Win32_Directory Where Name = 'C:\\Data'")`